# fn object could not be casted to a var object

Tags: clojure

First there is a function a:

```
(defn a[] nil)
```

If var called with a, the result is:

```
(var a)
#'user/a
```

But this throws an error:

```
(var (first [a]))
CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

My real problem is to retrieve meta data from a fn object, which is inside a hash-map. Therefore, I first need to convert

(:fn-name a-hash-map)

to a var object. But I get the error above.